# How to get a multi-step form working on Netlify with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby, netlify

I'm trying to get a multi-step form using Gatsby working using the Netlify Forms feature. I have split each form section into different components and iterate through them when needed. Whilst updating a hidden form on the page.

For some reason sometimes the hidden form appears with data-netlify="true" and sometimes it doesn't, I don't receive any form submissions in Netlify either way. The form is built to the static html though.

```
<form
  name="contact"
  method="POST"
  data-netlify="true"
  style={{ opacity: '0', width: '0', height: '0' }}>
  <input name="name" type="text" value={form.name} />
  <input name="phone" type="number" value={form.phone} />
  <input name="email" type="text" value={form.email} />
  <input name="additionalInfo" type="text" value={form.additionalInfo} />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button style={{ marginLeft: '3%' }} type="button" onClick={() => 
  stepBack()}>Back</button>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was missing this line. Adding it fixed everything.

```js
<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="Contact Us" />
```

So the form looks like this now.

```js
<form
  name="contact"
  method="POST"
  data-netlify="true"
  style={{ opacity: '0', width: '0', height: '0' }}>
  <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
  <input name="name" type="text" value={form.name} />
  <input name="phone" type="number" value={form.phone} />
  <input name="email" type="text" value={form.email} />
  <input name="additionalInfo" type="text" value={form.additionalInfo} />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button style={{ marginLeft: '3%' }} type="button" onClick={() => 
  stepBack()}>Back</button>
</form>
```